# How to sum a current value of a first variable and a previous value of the a new created variable

Tags: r, sum

I am quit new in using rstudio, I am trying to created a new variable that is based on the sum current value of the first variable and the previous values coming from the new created variable as shown.

```
mean    std     z       score
230.00  16.02   0.50    0.50
226.86  16.12   -0.56   0.0
227.57  16.99   0.85    0.85
231.14  19.74   -0.55   0.30
236.57  12.29   1.96    2.26
241.14  13.97   3.28    5.55
241.57  13.87   1.05    6.60
246.29  18.18   0.85    7.45
```

The calculation here are made using excel but I would like to do the same using rstudio.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thank you Ismail

Comment: Are you doing this on the `mean` column or `score`

Comment: Looks like `cumsum(df$z)`